# Meteor - Add twilio client library

Tags: meteor, twilio

I'm trying to add the twilio client library and have had no luck with any of the solutions I've looked up. I have tried including the script in client/lib, client/compatibility, client/lib/compatibility, and I always get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I think it is throwing this error because it is trying to inject itself and is not able to because of the way Meteor compiles the files. Has anyone had any luck including this library? I  would GREATLY appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work is to install the bower package, then install the meteor client library through bower.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to add twilio package to your project.

```
npm install twilio
```

and you can giv your SID and Token at server

```
var twilio = Npm.require('twilio')('ACCOUNT_SID', 'AUTH_TOKEN');
```

now you can make call to twilio api in server.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That isn't the library I'm having the problem with. It's the helper library that is used to make calls to and from the browser. Maybe I'm just confused but it seems like you need both of them to make this work.